# R text mining package DocumentTermMatrix with a dictionary in the control list takes way too much memory

Tags: r, memory-management, text-mining, tm, term-document-matrix

I have noticed that `DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus, control=list(dictionary=myDict))` consumes way more memory than `DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus)`

Why is this happening?

Any leads?

Here is the code snippet:

```
library(tm)
library(XML)
source("MyXMLReader.r") # contains the myXML reader code 
myCorpus <- Corpus(DirSource(paste(basepath,"corpus",sep=""))
readerControl = list(reader = myXMLReader))
myDict = unlist(readLines("some-file-containing-a-fixed-vocab"))
```

Now here is my question:

```
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(mYCorpus) # takes very little extra RAM to do this
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus,control=list(dictionary=myDict)) # Takes a whole lot of # RAM` which is not even released after dtm is formed...
```

I guess there is a memory leak and possible bug.

Comment: Put your question into context. What packages you're using, what you're trying to do, what have you done so far to pinpoint the behavior...

Comment: Thanks Roman Lustrik,

I am using R text mining package to index a corpus.

Here is the code snippet

library(tm) library(XML) source("MyXMLReader.r") # contains the myXML reader code myCorpus <- Corpus(DirSource(paste(basepath,"corpus",sep="")),readerControl = list(reader = myXMLReader)) myDict = unlist(readLines("some-file-containing-a-fixed-vocab")

Comment: can you supply some data please? No one can reproduce if we don't have data.

Comment: This was asked 5 years ago, don't know what version but it must be a very old version, doesn't state any numbers on memory usage, and no dataset so we can't reproduce. Voting to close as irreproducible...